# Can the Universe Be Infinite?

Tags: metaphysics, universe, infinity

Some think that the universe is infinite. To convince one in the creditability of the idea they point mainly at our inability to conceive of its spatial limits. Hence, here, I use 'infinity' (of the universe) just the same way--namely, no finite number can measure it.

Imagine they are correct. Infinity of anything means that it will have both infinite spatial parts being at finite distance and infinite ones removed infinitely from one another. If so, and given the limited speed of the interaction between the objects (parts) of the universe, there would be infinite parts of the universe infinitely isolated from one another; they would 'never' interact with one another. In that case, the universe might cease to maintain its unity and thus, to hold universal laws, physics claims to study.

So, can the universe be infinite or in other words, can the idea of our inability to imagine the universe's spatial limits be viewed as a counterbalance to that of the unity (universal laws) of the universe?

[image]

Comment: Infinite universe does not imply "there would be infinite parts infinitely removed from one another". The Euclidean 3D space is infinite, but any of its parts are at finite distance from each other. Even if it had such causally isolated parts there is no problem with them sharing universal laws. Indeed, in special relativity parts of the universe are causally isolated if they are spacelike separated, but still obey the same laws. By the way, non-existence of spatial limits does not imply infinite size, spheres in any dimension have no limits, but have finite size.

Comment: Infinity of anything means that it will have both infinite spatial parts being at finite distance and infinite ones removed infinitely from one another. To communicate at a limited speed, say c, the latter will need infinite time. They would exist like 'parallel spaces.' The problem with this, arising to physics, is that the universality of laws  of the universe would become the matter of chance rather than necessity. In this sense, its subject becomes blurred.

Comment: I suggest that you clarify in your post what "infinite universe" is supposed to mean, currently it is obscure. And the universality of laws is contingent even when the regions are causally connected: there is no logical problem with the inverse square law turning into inverse cube law, for example, beyond some spatial boundary. We simply take universality as a methodological assumption for the sake of simplicity of description. If we discover that some law is not universal it is simply no longer counted as "fundamental". The drift of "fundamental" constants is actively discussed, for example.

Comment: I will consider your suggestion. Actually, this line of reasoning as it is just attempts to show that declaring infinity without making additional qualification risks leaving physics without the 'fundamental' laws as such.

Comment: By the way, in my post I cite the idea of infinity of the universe the way in which its adepts, not me, mainly support it, which now I have made more salient in the post.

Comment: I'd suggest that the idea of infinite extension is paradoxical and not plausible. It's a problematic idea that arises from naive realism.

Comment: “Some think”. Who are you referring to?

Comment: @PeterJ "the idea of infinite extension is paradoxical and not plausible" Based on what, precisely?

Comment: @Mark From Giordano Bruno to the guys  answering and commenting respectively on this page. Actually, I refer to the idea itself.

Comment: @NoahSchweber - Based on common sense. There is also the problem that Infinite extension would require BB theory to be wrong. Finite extension also makes no sense. In short, extension makes no sense. Welcome to metaphysics.

Comment: @PeterJ "Based on common sense." Yeah, I don't see that at all. Frankly, neither option *fails* to make sense to me.

Comment: @NoahSchweber - Fair enough. Most philosophers find the problem more difficult. .

Comment: @PeterJ Common sense is a poor guide beyond common circumstances for which it was developed, and from which most of fundamental science and metaphysics are far removed. Bib Bang is consistent with infinite extension (of spacetime), and under current expansion projections the spacetime is infinite (expansion never stops).

Comment: @Conifold  Something that is expanding is clearly finite, while a finite beginning to extension cannot lead to infinite extension. Common sense is what I rely on at all times. It seems we don't agree about much here.

Comment: @PeterJ Spacetime is infinite, "expanding" is just a layman's description relying on the traditional separation between time and space, which breaks down in relativity. But even something infinite can easily expand (think of an infinite strip widening), or have "finite beginning" (like the tip of an infinite cone). As you can see, common sense can easily mislead you, at least in math and physics.

Comment: @Conifold - Do you not mean 'potentially infinite'? Clearly something expanding is not infinitely extended. Why can I not call space a bad infinity? Common sense tells me that infinite space has not always existed. in which case space cannot be infinite. Ditto for time. I've not before come across anyone simply stating that time and space are infinite. .

Comment: @PeterJ The separation of space and time is just another failure of common sense, it is abandoned in relativity. So are Aristotelian distinctions for infinity. However, that spacetime is infinite under Big Rip scenarios is obvious even naively, it is an infinite cone. So is that infinite can expand, see the example above, or take space adding new dimension every hour.

Comment: @Conifold - Common sense tells me that time and space are not separable. It tells me that if temporal or spatial extension is infinite it is in the sense that the number-line is infinite, not in the sense that it is an infinite object but in the sense it is unlimited. My argument is aganst the idea that space-time is an infinite object, not against the idea it can always be further extended. Does this deal with our differences?

Comment: @PeterJ In modern mathematics the number line is "actually" infinite (there is no analog of "potential" infinity there). So is the spacetime, the prevailing interpretations of relativity are eternalist, reconciling it with presentism (which I am guessing you express with "potential" and "further extendable") requires non-relativistic add-ons. I am not sure what your argument is beyond the reference to common sense, which seems to be just a shorthand for what you believe. Infinite extension is certainly not paradoxical, and its plausibility is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @PeterJ "Something that is expanding is clearly finite" Based on what, precisely? There are plenty of ways we can talk about an infinite set getting bigger. Also, expansion is really a "local" phenomenon (it's not that we're observing a "boundary" moving away from us, it's that we're observing objects in the universe moving away from each other); by analogy, consider the map x->2x on the reals. I think the real takeaway from this sort of point is that common sense really isn't to be trusted at this point, but common meta-sense says that's not really surprising - why **should** it be, a priori?

Comment: @Conifold 'an infinite set getting bigger'; 'something infinite can easily expand.' Anything that expands is getting _bigger_, _greater_ in space (Can anything be big or bigger in the time dimension as such?). Isn't it? Then, that something is varying in _size_, thus, has _relative_ spatial extent in spacetime, thus by definition is _measurable_. It has measurable dimensions—that is, we can project its dimensions towards the line number’s respective numbers.

Comment: But would its infinity property allow us measure it, for we have the infinite line-number but do not have the number 'infinity' on it? What expands is measurable by numbers on the number line, but infinity property of anything is not measurable at all, because there is no such number as infinity. 'Infinity expands' is a contradiction, for it would mean that what is measurable for us at the same time is immeasurable for us.

Comment: In my opinion, the improper and careless use of the meaning of infinity underlies the issues of metaphysics, math, and physics; for example, such expression as ‘an infinite number of finite numbers’ easily makes us think that infinity is a number-like thing, when it is not.

Comment: @Giorgi Spatial size is not Lorentz invariant, in other words, it does not measure anything real in relativity, it is an artifact of a particular choice of frame (roughly, attached to the Earth). Different frame, different size, different rate of expansion. Infinities can be measured by various metrics, dimension, cardinality, etc., so there is no problem with them expanding, or the expansion can be an artifact of the description, as it is with the spacetime. And number infinity can be easily added to the line, if one wants it, it is called compactification. We'll just get the projective line.

Answer (score 2):

There are several major assumptions here which you haven't justified (and which I don't see how to justify):

---

> there would be infinite parts infinitely removed from one another.

The set of natural numbers is infinite, but any two natural numbers are only finitely far apart. We can have "local finitude" but "global infinitude."

> given the limited speed of the interaction between the objects (parts) of the universe, there would be infinite parts of the universe infinitely isolated from one another, so that the universe is very likely to cease to maintain its unity and thus, to hold universal laws

Wy should parts of the universe infinitely far apart (even if such exist) behave significantly differently from each other? (Also, what does "unity" mean here?) And this is ignoring the possibility of physical interactions which don't depend on distance - there's nothing a priori impossibile about two objects sharing a relationship despite being far apart from each other in space.

> can the idea of our impossibility of imagining the universe's spatial limits be viewed as a counterbalance to that of the unity (universal laws) of the universe

Here you seem to be conflating *knowledge* with *truth* - the universe may have fundamental properties which we can never know, and while that may be annoying there's nothing wrong with that a priori.

---

The question of whether it's possible for the universe to be infinite is very hard to even **phrase precisely**, let alone answer. But certainly I see no serious objection to that possibility here, nor am I aware of such. So I believe the answer to the title question is:

### As far as we know, yes.

Comment: Infinity of anything means that it will have both infinite spatial parts being at finite distance and infinite ones removed infinitely from one another. To communicate at a limited speed, say c, the latter will need infinite time. They would exist like 'parallel spaces.' The problem with this, arising to physics, is that the universality of laws  of the universe would become the matter of chance rather than necessity. In this sense, its subject becomes blurred. Notice too that the question opposes to each other the two ideas rather than conflates them.

Comment: By the 'unity' I mean that the energy conservation law is applicable to the whole of the universe, for example.

Comment: @Giorgi "and infinite ones removed infinitely from one another." ...does it now?  Consider the set of all finite integers greater than 0.  That set has an infinite number of members, but by definition every number in the set is finite (because that's the set we're considering... the one containing only finite numbers).  It follows that the distance between any two numbers in this set is also finite.  So, which is it... are you claiming this set is finite (if so, how big is it?)  Or are you claiming that there are elements in this set an infinite distance from each other (which ones?)

Comment: @H Walters If I have understood you correctly, we have in the set an infinite number of finite numbers. Let us consider, then, the possibility of there being the greatest possible distance between the two farthest elements ever in the set. Imagine there is such a thing, and thus the set is finite. But how this would correspond with an infinite number of the finite elements? The latter would mean that, whenever you would want to measure a distance between them and reply to the question ‘How big is it?’ there always would appear an additional in-between element expanding the set. (continued)

Comment: @H Walters So, you cannot measure it and respond definitely to the question. In this sense the set is infinite. And these elements would be ‘those ones’ that are necessary to prevent the set from ‘misbehavior’-- the deviation from its ‘nature’ or definition. So, there in the set with an infinite number of finite elements certainly will be, as it seems to me at least, ‘infinite ones removed infinitely from one another.’

Comment: @Noah Oooops. I mean 'Notice too that the question deliberately opposes to each other the two ideas rather than conflates 'knowledge' and 'truth.'

Comment: @Giorgi I disagree with the notion that the set having only finite numbers in it means its size is finite.  If M is its finite size, then M+1 is also a finite number, so it should contain M+1 since it has all of them.  But since it contains all numbers from 1..M+1, then by definition of counting it is at least size M+1 (since we can count M+1 elements).  Another way to think about it is, for any finite number M, no matter how large, this set is larger than that finite number M.  So it is infinite.

Comment: Now consider any two numbers; hypothetically, X and Y where X<Y and X and Y are an infinite distance away.  Add one more number to consider: 1; so we have 1<=X<Y, since that's a minimum.  The distance from 1 to Y is Y-1 (or pred Y if you prefer).  Surely the distance then from X to Y must be less than or equal to that, meaning it must be less than Y.  But if Y is a finite number, that means the distance from X to Y must be finite, right?  So the *only* way you can have X and Y be an infinite distance from each other is for Y to be infinite, and we simply don't have infinites in the set.

Comment: @Giorgi Do you understand that the set of (say) natural numbers is infinite, but the distance between any two specific natural numbers is finite (but can be arbitrarily large finite)? It seems to me that your comments are making the issue more complicated than it actually is - we have an example which is already well-known and easy to understand.

Comment: @H Walters Frankly, I am a bit confused by your first comment on my previous comment. It seems to me that that your conclusion ('I disagree with the notion that the set having only finite numbers in it means its size is finite.' and 'So it is infinite.' is the same with mine ('In this sense the set is infinite. '). Correct me if I have misunderstood your arguments and example. But actually, my post is not about whether the universe is infinite or not; rather, it is about what can follow from the statement that the universe is infinite.

Comment: @Noah @H Anyhow, I think that you conflate math's space with a physical space. The former's members are numbers  containing one another (Y contains X, and both of them 1 on a natural numbers line). We have a different case with physical objects in the universe. They do not contain one another; to the contrary, they are separated by space, so infinite finite elements in space (consider that even between Y and X there are infinite rational members on numbers line that can measure phys objects in space) would lead to the infinite universe. But this is a topic of a different conversation (post).

Comment: @H Walters ‘It follows that the distance between any two numbers in this set is also finite.’ It follows only that the difference between any two numbers on number line is finite. In an infinite physical space it is not obvious that the distance between any of its two finite elements is necessarily finite. Consider propositions: ‘the distance between any two finite integers in finite space is necessarily finite’ and ‘the distance between any two finite integers in infinite space is necessarily finite,’ and imagine one says both are true.

Comment: Consider that the former is necessarily true. But if the latter is necessarily true too, the independent meaning of infinity is ignored, as well as blurred, for replacing finiteness with its opposite ‘infinity’ in the proposition(s) changes nothing in its truth-falsity conditions. Thus, given that finiteness and infinity have their independent meanings, the statement that ‘the distance between any two finite integers in infinite space is necessarily finite’ can be true at best contingently rather than necessarily;

Comment: and therefore, under the given conditions, you cannot necessarily or strictly prove against the proposition according to which, the distance between at least some finite integers in infinite space is infinite. But this is what the proposition ‘It follows that the distance between any two numbers in this set is also finite’ actually does.

Comment: @Giorgi Your comment was: "Infinity of anything means that it will have both infinite spatial parts being at finite distance and infinite ones removed infinitely from one another."  All I'm doing is disputing this comment.  In doing so, it suffices to show that there is an infinity of *something* that does not have parts infinitely removed from one another.  That's the burden I'm taking and have met with the example of the set containing all and only finite non-negative integers.

Comment: s/non-negative/positive/

Comment: @Giorgi I think this has hit the point of diminishing returns, and comment threads are not for extended discussion (also I keep getting pinged with each response :P); it might be best to continue this in a chatroom if you both want to (I'll bow out though).

Comment: @HWalters See my above comment.

Comment: Agreed, but Giorgi needs 10 more rep.  (I'll refrain from further replies; I just want to make it clear... Giorgi should *gain* that rep and open this in chat; feel free to flag what's here to remove clutter).

Comment: I agree too. I could, perhaps, sometime.